# RoR - uninitialized constant Twitter::Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, rubygems

**twitter_helper.rb**

```
module TwitterHelper

  require 'rubygems'
  require 'twitter'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'uri'


  def get_tweets (twitter_user)
    begin
        @tweets = Array.new
        @twitter = Twitter::Client.new

        Twitter.user_timeline(twitter_user) do |tweet|
            @tweets.push(tweet)
        end
        @tweets
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e
      _("Errors: #{e.to_s}
        ")
    end
  end

end
```

My gemfile includes

```
gem 'twitter'
```

And I've done

```
bundle install
```

But every time I call

```
tweets = get_tweets
```

From my view I get the exception (uninitialized constant Twitter::Client). What am I missing?

Comment: after you added the gem to your GemFile did you restart your server? I ask this because I don't get this error when I run your code in isolation. Try this (a) rails c (b) include TwitterHelper (c) get_tweets(user)

Comment: Where is this module located?

Comment: Thanks for the help guys... apparently some dependency conflicts was making bundler install twitter .9, which is significantly different from >=1.0. After I fixed those dependencies I was able to install twitter >=1.0. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but here goes.

Check the version number. Significant changes were made between the twitter gem <1.0 and >=1.0. You should specify

```
gem 'twitter', '>= 1.0'
```

And then

```
bundle install
```

And resolve any dependency conflicts (if you get any).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite unusual to have the imports inside the module, have them outside and see

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

module TwitterHelper
  def get_tweets (twitter_user)
    begin
        @tweets = Array.new
        @twitter = Twitter::Client.new

        Twitter.user_timeline(twitter_user) do |tweet|
            @tweets.push(tweet)
        end
        @tweets
    rescue Exception => e
      puts e
      _("Errors: #{e.to_s}
        ")
    end
  end

end
```